# how to parse backslash json structure using jquery parse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, angularjs

This is my code. I have used jquery parse. Can you Please help me? How to parse this?

```
var jsondata= {
  "forms": [
    "{\"lat\":11.913859799999999,\"lng\":79.8144722}",
    "{\"lat\":11.913859799999999,\"lng\":79.8144722}"
  ]
}
var a=$.parseJSON(jsondata);
 alert(a.forms[0].lat); // not working show "undefined"
```

error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,

Comment: Why are there backslashes in the text?

Comment: i am using sailsjs backend.  return json this format. i have stored my db field json value structure. so

Comment: There is nothing to parse, `jsondata` is already an object.

Comment: That code throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o`. Try providing a code example that actually demonstrates your problem.

Comment: yes. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o this error showing

Comment: @Angu — Start by giving us the code that you have that produces the error message you get.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the `forms[0]` element to convert it to a real object:

```js
var jsondata= {
  "forms": [
    "{\"lat\":11.913859799999999,\"lng\":79.8144722}",
    "{\"lat\":11.913859799999999,\"lng\":79.8144722}"
  ]
}

var result = document.querySelector('pre');

result.textContent = JSON.parse(jsondata.forms[0]).lat;
//                   ^ parse here

// parse all elements of jsondata.forms:
// first: convert the elements of jsondata.forms to objects
jsondata.forms = jsondata.forms.map(function (v) { return JSON.parse(v); });

// now the jsondata.forms elements are objects
result.textContent += '\n\nThe converted jsondata.forms Array\n' +
                      JSON.stringify(jsondata.forms, null, ' ') + 
                      '\n\nso: jsondata.forms[1].lng = ' + jsondata.forms[1].lng;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: var a=JSON.parse(jsondata.forms);
                    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
                            alert(a[i].lat);
                    }  // not working

Answer (score 0):

I think the backend is generating a wrong response to your application

Sample like this lets say i have an array of

```
$data['default'] = array(
    array(
        'email' => 'sample@gmail.com',
        'username' => 'username1'
    ),

    array(
        'email' => 'sample@yahoo.com',
        'username' => 'username2'
    ),

    array(
        'email' => 'sample@hot.com',
        'username' => 'username3'
    )
);

$data['title'] = 'Sample';
```

and use

```
echo json_encode(json_encode($data));die();
```

would result to a data like this

```
"{\"default\":[{\"email\":\"sample@gmail.com\",\"username\":\"username1\"},{\"email\":\"sample@yahoo.com\",\"username\":\"username2\"},{\"email\":\"sample@hot.com\",\"username\":\"username3\"}],\"title\":\"Sample\"}"
```

but if use only

```
echo json_encode($data);die();
```

It would create a valid json data

```
{
    "default": [
        {
            "email": "sample@gmail.com",
            "username": "username1"
        },
        {
            "email": "sample@yahoo.com",
            "username": "username2"
        },
        {
            "email": "sample@hot.com",
            "username": "username3"
        }
    ],
    "title": "Sample"
}
```

Using your data

```
var jsondata= {
  "forms": [
    "{\"lat\":11.913859799999999,\"lng\":79.8144722}",
    "{\"lat\":11.913859799999999,\"lng\":79.8144722}"
  ]
};
```

and using some jQuery code:

```
$.each(jsondata.forms, function(i, me){
console.log(JSON.parse(me));
});
```

using navite javascript

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsondata.forms.length; i++) {
 console.log(JSON.parse(jsondata.forms[i]));
}
```

returns

```
{lat: 11.913859799999999, lng: 79.8144722}
{lat: 11.913859799999999, lng: 79.8144722}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON is not JavaScript! It is a data serialization format.

```
var jsondata = 
    "{ \"forms\": ["
    + "{\"lat\":11.913859799999999,\"lng\":79.8144722} , "
    + "{\"lat\":11.913859799999999,\"lng\":79.8144722} ] }"

var a = JSON.parse(jsondata)
```

- no need for jQuery -- the JavaScript language provides native `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`
- JSON data must be one long, single string that is passed to `parse`
- JSON keys have to be quoted